# How is the $\text{CNOT}$ gate equivalent to $\text{XOR}$?

Tags: quantum-gate

This is a screenshot from my lecture:

[image]

Why does the $\text{CNOT}$ here output $a ⊕ b$? Does the "$⊕$" operation even make sense for a quantum state?

Answer (score 3):

Consider action of the $\text{CNOT}$ on the basis states $\{ |00\rangle,|01\rangle,|10\rangle,|11\rangle \}\,.$

$$|00\rangle \to |00\rangle \,, $$
$$|01\rangle \to |01\rangle \,, $$
$$|10\rangle \to |11\rangle \,, $$
$$|11\rangle \to |10\rangle \,. $$

Now, comparing this with $|ab\rangle$, You can observe that
$$|a,b\rangle \to |a, a\oplus b\rangle \,. $$

Hence, the notation makes sense. $\text{CNOT}$ keeps the control qubit as it is and performs the $\text{XOR}$ operation of two states and outputs the result in the second, the target qubit.

Comment: Thanks @FDGod ! This makes sense for basis states, but how would it look like if both inputs were in a superposition? Like:
$$\alpha_1|0\rangle +  \beta_1|1\rangle $$
$$\alpha_2|0\rangle +  \beta_2|1\rangle $$

Comment: Does [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/10075/how-does-the-cnot-gate-work?rq=1) help?